# Within the map array the value is correct, but when prop is sent to component the values in array selection combines

Tags: reactjs, node.js, react-hooks

I'm not sure if my title makes sense, but I am working with a map that is going through my array of ducks. Inside the array, everything looks good, but when it gets to sending my values to the next component it combines the values.

Here is a screenshot:
[Image of error, showing the correct value in array but in correct value in duckLocation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEDUW.png)

In case you can't see the photo... 

When I check the map/ducks/array it shows: 
[{"duckLocation": {"left": "99px","top": "650px"},"duckPic": 2}]

And in duckLocation it shows: 
{"duckLocation": {"left": "99px","top": "650px"},"duckPic": 2}

When grabbing duckPic, it shows the correctly. 
duckPic: 2

In my opinion, somewhere along the way duckLocation is set to ducks[arrayPlace] and then is sent over; however, I cannot find where this is happening.

This is what my code looks like:

```
export const SummonDuckWrapper = () => {
  const [ducks, setDucks] = useState([])

  const addDuck = (duck, picture) => {
    setDucks([...ducks, { duckLocation: duck, duckPic: picture }])
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect ducks' + ducks)
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <SummonDuckButton addDuck={addDuck} />
      {ducks.map((duckLocation, duckPic, index) => (
        <Duck location={duckLocation} picture={duckPic} key={index} />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
export const SummonDuckButton = ({ addDuck }) => {
    const [left, setLeft] = useState(0);
    const [top, setTop] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        setLeft(Math.floor(Math.random() * screen.width));
        setTop(Math.floor(Math.random() * screen.height));
    }, []);


    const summonDuck = () => {
        setLeft(Math.floor(Math.random() * screen.width));
        setTop(Math.floor(Math.random() * screen.height));

        const duckLocation = {
            left: left + 'px',
            top: top + 'px'
        }

        const duckPic = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

        addDuck(duckLocation, duckPic)
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={summonDuck}>
            Summon Duck
        </button>
    )
}
```

The reason why I need duckLocation to just have the left and top is so I can use them to style a div to place some ducks when a button is pushed. I have another file that calls the duckLocation as a prop, but it doesn't do anything to change it and shouldn't be the one affecting what is happening.

Any help or ideas is much appreciated!

Comment: I guess, this is a destructuring problem.. Change the map like to `ducks.map(({duckLocation, duckPic}, index) => (` -> If you don't wrap your `duckLocation` and `duckPic` inside a `{}`, your dickPic becomes index and index becomes your original array.

Comment: Either you can do it as suggested above or simply change code to `{ducks.map((duck, index) => (
        <Duck location={duck.duckLocation} picture={duck.duckPic} key={index} />
      ))}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is certainly wrong:

```
ducks.map((duckLocation, duckPic, index) =>
```

The `map()` callback function receives [three arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

1. The object in the current iteration of the array
2. The index on the current iteration of the array
3. The array reference itself

If `duckLocation` and `duckPic` are properties on that object then they are not separate arguments to the function.  They're properties on the *first* argument to the function.  Which can be destructured:

```
ducks.map(({ duckLocation, duckPic }, index) =>
```

Comment: I didn't know that! Thanks! It has fixed my problem!